# Deleting a Tag Wiki body causes site error

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

If you edit a tag wiki, remove all of the text in the tag wiki body, and save edits, you get the ["workin on ur problemz" error message.](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/tags/edit-tag-wiki/submit/59853)

In this particular case, the tag wiki excerpt and the tag wiki body contained exactly the same text, so it made sense to try and eliminate the duplication in of the tag wiki body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is now supported. We generally don't like post records with empty bodies, I guess except in this case.

Comment: Im not sure I support allowing empty wikis or empty excerpts, Im going to put a minimal length required here

Comment: @waffles still valid in the case someone takes an empty wiki and types in noise. You'd revert to.. empty.

Comment: I can add a mod function to "wipe" the wiki out for that ... I guess

Comment: Isn't the Tag Wiki body merely a Notes field (nvarchar max)?  There's widespread industry support for notes fields being empty; I'm a little puzzled by the discomfort.  Also, there are reasons to have an empty tag wiki body; some tags just need a summary description: "Use this tag for...".  Make it required, and people will just duplicate the summary description, which is what I was trying to fix in the first place.

Comment: @Robert my main concern is the blank or really short wiki excerpts, also a 5 char wiki summary makes no sense, I can live with excerpt and no summary, that is not a big problem imho