# Site error: proposing a new excerpt-only tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

I've just created a new tag on SO so I tried to create a tag wiki for it. Since I'm not an expert on the topic I wrote an excerpt only, but when I tried to submit it I got the 'oops' cat error page.

I don't have enough rep / votes on the tag to really edit it so my submission was a proposed edit only. I tried this for [an existing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/erp/info) too, and it also crashed. I then tried filling in a tag wiki body too - in this case just a link to Wikipedia - and it saved correctly.

Repro steps:

- pick a tag with no existing wiki
- edit tag info
- write an excerpt only + submit - crash
- go back (you may need to reload the page: the save button didn't re-enable) and write a body for the wiki as well as the excerpt + submit - saves OK

I'm not clear whether this depends on whether you have permission to edit the wiki for the specific tag - there aren't any tags I do have enough votes to edit regardless, nor do I have enough total rep to edit everywhere.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80031/deleting-a-tag-wiki-body-causes-site-error

Comment: Not exactly a crash, more like a thrown exception.

Comment: @Robert yes, true - "site error" fits better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completed with a few strings attached:

1. We now require that Tag Excerpt Wikis are 20 chars or longer
2. We now require that Tag Wikis are either empty or 30 chars or longer

As a side effect this issue is fixed