# Wiki Tag Editing Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Site error: proposing a new excerpt-only tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80105/site-error-proposing-a-new-excerpt-only-tag-wiki)

Hi!

On StackOverflow:

1. Be a user who cannot edit or create tag wikis, but who can propose the tag summary.
2. Tag a question with a new tag (e.g., `jasper-reports-server`).
3. Edit the new tag.
4. Do not include a wiki, edit only the summary.
5. Submit to propose the new tag and its description:

   JasperReports Server is a Java-based application that facilitates creating ad hoc reports using a web browser (based on the JasperReports API).

Crash.